# Moving an object along a straight line at a constant speed from point A to B

Tags: javascript, canvas, trigonometry

**I know this has been asked a few times before, but there has been no answer that actually works that I can find. There is a similar one, but the speed varies depending on the distance travelled.**

So my problem is that I am trying to get an object (a player in this case) to move a long a straight line from point A to B at a constant speed. This is done by clicking on the player and dragging to where I want him to walk to, so it can be in any direction and over any distance.

I have some code that very nearly works, but the player always ends up slightly off course, more so the longer the distance he travels is. Here is that code:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    selectedPlayer.moveX = e.pageX;
    selectedPlayer.moveY = e.pageY;
    movePlayer(selectedPlayer);
});

function movePlayer(player) {

    var xDistance = player.moveX - player.x;
    var yDistance = player.moveY - player.y;
    var travelDistance = Math.sqrt((xDistance * xDistance) + (yDistance * yDistance));
    var timeToTravel = travelDistance; //This may seem pointless, but I will add a speed variable later
    var playerAngle = Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance) * (180 / Math.PI);
    var xRatio = Math.atan2(xDistance, travelDistance);
    var yRatio = Math.atan2(yDistance, travelDistance);

    //This function is called in another part of code that repeats it 60 times a second
    walkPlayer = function() {

        setTimeout(function(){
            player.x = player.moveX;
            player.y = player.moveY;
            selectedPlayer = undefined;
            walkPlayer = undefined;
        }, timeToTravel * 20)

        player.angle = playerAngle;
        player.x += xRatio;
        player.y += yRatio;
    };
}
```

I hope this makes sense, I've had to include only the part of the code that is relevant. I think my issue probably lies with the xRatio and yRatio parts, but I can't figure it out; I'm completely stumped.

EDIT: I'd like to add that playerAngle makes the player face in the direction of the drag, and that part works fine.

Comment: Are x and y int's? Because movement will likely require a float to be stable. (I'm not super javascript literate, so maybe var is the right thing? )

Comment: What is that `setTimeout` supposed to do? Especially if called 60 times per second?

Comment: @Bergi it's a (bad) attempt at getting the player to stop at the right spot. It works but is pretty buggy and inefficient. Not had time to look over that part yet though, since I've been trying to sort out the main issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/CajbL/)**

Below are the basics required to get what you need working,

```
var tx = targetX - x,
    ty = targetY - y,
    dist = Math.sqrt(tx*tx+ty*ty),
    rad = Math.atan2(ty,tx),
    angle = rad/Math.PI * 180;;

    velX = (tx/dist)*thrust;
    velY = (ty/dist)*thrust;

player.x += velX
player.y += velY
```

This is a demo I did a while back which sounds like what you are looking for, I added the ability to click in order to change the target based off of your issue.

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    targetX  = e.pageX;
    targetY = e.pageY;
});

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    x = 300,
    y = 0,
    targetX = Math.random()*300,
    targetY = Math.random()*300,
    velX = 0,
    velY = 0,
    thrust = 5;


function draw(){   
    var tx = targetX - x,
        ty = targetY - y,
        dist = Math.sqrt(tx*tx+ty*ty),
        rad = Math.atan2(ty,tx),
        angle = rad/Math.PI * 180;;

    velX = (tx/dist)*thrust;
    velY = (ty/dist)*thrust;

    // stop the box if its too close so it doesn't just rotate and bounce
    if(dist > 1){
      x += velX;
      y += velY;
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(x, y, 10, 10);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(targetX, targetY, 10, 10);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    setTimeout(function(){draw()}, 30);   
}

draw();
```

Comment: That looks very much like what I'm looking for, thank you! I'll try adapting it a bit for my code and see if it works and get back to you on it.

Comment: @JamieRushworth yeah I kind of rushed posted it, I wrote a bit of an explanation above and modified my code example to base its target off of where the user clicks.

Comment: This works much better, thanks! Thanks for the update with the mouse click too, although in your demo it seems to bounce around the target which seems a bit odd. I think its because there isn't actually anything stopping the draw function once it has reached its destination?

Comment: @Loktar: The white point is flickering when it has reached its target.

Comment: yeah it just keeps rotating hitting the target, nothing is actually stopping it thats why.

Comment: Alright the fiddle is fixed. Just checks the distance if its < 1 it stops.

Comment: It still flickers half of the time, but I have used the time method from @Bergi for that. I can't upvote your post till I get 15 reputation, but I'll make sure I do when I can!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem seems to be that `xRatio` and `yRatio` are angles, not vector coordinates. This should work:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    movePlayer(selectedPlayer, {x:e.pageX, y:e.pageY});
});

function movePlayer(player, target) {
    var start = {
            x: player.x,
            y: player.y,
            t: Date.now()
        },
        distance = Math.sqrt(distance.x*distance.x + distance.y*distance.y),
        time = distance; //This may seem pointless, but I will add a speed variable later
        difference = {
            x: target.x - player.x,
            y: target.y - player.y,
            t: time
        };

    player.angle = Math.atan2(distance.y, distance.x) * (180 / Math.PI);

    //This function is called in another part of code that repeats it 60 times a second
    walkPlayer = function(curTime) { // we need timing information here: Date.now()
        var elapsed = curTime - start.t,
            ratio = elapsed / difference.t;
        player.x = start.x + difference.x * ratio;
        player.y = start.y + difference.y * ratio;
        if (ratio >= 1) {
            player.x = target.x;
            player.y = target.y;
            // end calling of walkPlayer
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have used your time part and it works great. I can't upvote your post till I get 15 reputation, but I'll make sure to do so when I can!