# How to move an object into a specific direction with a constant speed?

Tags: variables, calculation

I want to move an object into a specific direction. 
Here is the method I'm using:

```
    private void calculateDirection(float aimX, float aimY) {
       // calculating distance to target
       float xDistance = aimX - x;
       float yDistance = aimY - y;
       x += xDistance / 10 * speed * delta();
       y += yDistance / 10 * speed * delta();
    }
```

It works good so far, but as you can see the x and y variables are divided by 10 which leads to the object moving fast firstly and then, when xDistance and yDistance getting smaller the object gets slower and slower.
How do I make a calculation that moves the object in the exact same speed all the time?

I already tried something like this:

```
x += xDistance / +xDistance;
```

but it won't work somehow.

Comment: what is your programing language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving an object along a straight line at a constant speed from point A to B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849185/moving-an-object-along-a-straight-line-at-a-constant-speed-from-point-a-to-b)   (This answer is in javascript, but the trigonometry will be the same in any language)

Comment: My programming language is Java